# Can (jni call) `DeleteLocalRef` be used on native function arguments

Tags: java-native-interface, android-ndk

Ran into the ReferenceTable limit in my Android jni function. Cleaned it up with `DeleteLocalRef`, but I want to know if I should do the same for the arguments passed to the function from Java. Is it possible? If so, is it worthwhile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local references are created within a native method only. I dont think it is worthwhile doing that for the function arguments. Best practice will be to delete the local references if you are doing anything  in a loop, or creating a lot. Take a look at [sun's reference](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/refs.html)

Comment: So it's not worthwhile, but is it even possible? Handy to know if I get close to the ref limit again

Comment: I am not sure whether it is possible, but I am sure it isn't a good solution to getting close to the reference limit. A bit of refactoring may help, instead of trying patch-work solutions like this. Interesting thought though

Comment: I used to free the parameters (freeing everything for good measure), but it always caused an "invalid reference"-warning in the log